# Javascript object group by day,month,year

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, group-by, underscore.js

I am working on application which I need to do grouping of different sets of javascript object and those will be based on month,day and year.

For day I am doing like below

```
var calculateByDay = function(inputList){
        var outPutList = [];    
        var result = {}
        var item = null, key = null;
        for(i=0; c<inputList.length; i++) {
           item=inputList[c];
           key = Object.keys(item)[0];
           item=item[key];
           if(!result[key]) {
                result[key] = item;
            }
           else {
            result[key] += item;
        }
        for (r in result)
            {
                var docs = {};
                docs["date"] = r;
                docs["amount"] = result[r];
                outPutList.push(docs);
            }

        }
        return outPutList;
    }
```

How can I improve above code and use it for month and year calculation also? 
I went thorough underscore.js and it has a [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) method. but seems not fits with my requirement.
I want to group by months and year also,
for

```
var inputList = [{"2012-12-02T00:00": 2000}, {"2013-01-01T00:00": 1200},{"2013-02-02T00:00": 550}, {"2013-02-02T00:00": 1000}];
```

The output should be:

```
Monthly :
[{"December 2012": 2000}, {"January 2013": 1200},{"February 2013": 1550}];
Yearly
[{"year 2012": 2000}, {"year 2013": 2750}];
```

And it seems I need to this kind of map,reduce approach for large data(array sets), is there any other library or practices I can do to make the code solid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

Given a slightly different structure of data:

```
var data = [{
  "date": "2011-12-02T00:00",
  "value": 1000
}, {
  "date": "2013-03-02T00:00",
  "value": 1000
}, {
  "date": "2013-03-02T00:00",
  "value": 500
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-02T00:00",
  "value": 200
}, {
  "date": "2013-04-02T00:00",
  "value": 200
}, {
  "date": "2013-04-02T00:00",
  "value": 500
}, {
  "date": "2013-03-02T00:00",
  "value": 500
}, {
  "date": "2013-04-12T00:00",
  "value": 1000
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-02T00:00",
  "value": 600
}];
```

You could use underscore:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
    return item.date;
});

var groupedByYear = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
    return item.date.substring(0,4);
});

var groupedByMonth = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
    return item.date.substring(0,7);
});

console.log(groupedByYear);
```

See related answer: [Javascript - underscorejs map reduce groupby based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743628/javascript-underscorejs-map-reduce-groupby-based-on-date/16746590#16746590)

Answer (score 2):

Please see if the following refactor is useful for you
http://jsfiddle.net/wkUJC/

```
var dates = [{"2012-12-02T00:00": 2000}, {"2013-01-01T00:00": 1200},{"2013-02-02T00:00": 550}, {"2013-02-02T00:00": 1000}];

function calc(dates) {
    var response = {};
    dates.forEach(function(d){
        for (var k in d) {
            var _ = k.split("-");
            var year = _[0]
            var month = _[1]
            if (!response[year]) response[year] = {total: 0}
            response[year][month] = response[year][month] ? response[year][month]+d[k] : d[k]
            response[year].total+= d[k]
        }
    });
    console.log(response);
    return response;
}

calc(dates);
```

Comment: Thanks, btw I wanted response in a array.