# Javascript - underscorejs map reduce groupby based on date

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, mapreduce, underscore.js

I am working with underscorejs in a project. I need to do different types of array operations like map,reduce, filter groupby.

My dataset looks like below:

```
var data_list = [
     {"insertDate": "2011-12-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":10000}},
    {"insertDate": "2013-03-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":10000}
    },{"insertDate": "2013-03-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":10000}
    },{"insertDate": "2012-12-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":30000}},
  {"insertDate": "2013-04-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":10000},
    },{"insertDate": "2013-04-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":30000}
    },{"insertDate": "2013-03-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":20000}},
  {"insertDate": "2013-04-12T00:00","value": {"paisa":30000}
    },
    {"insertDate": "2012-11-02T00:00","value": {"paisa":10000}}
]
```

I want to calculated data based on day, month and year.
For day calculation I am doing groupby, then using map reduce for calculation.
Like below:

```
var groupedByDateData = _.groupBy(data_list, "insertDate");
var aggregateByDate = _.map(groupedByDateData, function(invoiceObject, createdat) {
  return { 
     createdat: createdat, 
     val: _.reduce(invoiceObject, function(m,x) { 
       return m + x.value.paisa;
     }, 0) 
  };
});
```

Its working fine for day based map reduce, but for month and year calculation I want to do in same format as the code readable.

How can I do map,reduce using underscorejs so that I can get data like below:
 For monthly calculation:

```
[{"createdat": "February 2011", "val": 10000}, 
{"createdat": "March 2013", "val": 40000}, 
{"createdat": "December 2012", "val": 30000}, 
{"createdat": "April 2013", "val": 70000}, 
{"createdat": "November 2012", "val": 10000}]
```

For yearly mapreduce:

```
[{"createdat": "2011", "val": 10000}, 
{"createdat": "2013", "val": 110000}, 
{"createdat": "2012", "val": 70000}]
```

My code [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ucohoq/2/edit) here

N.B: For getting yearly and monthly reduced result set I am splitting the date, but that is not best thing to do.
check out my solution here http://jsbin.com/etepan/3/edit

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to be grouping by different things (time, month, year), so the key is in the `groupBy`.

You're using this:

```
var groupedByDateData = _.groupBy(data_list, "insertDate");
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
var groupedByDateData = _.groupBy(data_list, function(item) {
  return item.insertDate; // returns "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00"
});
```

By modifying this function, you can change what groupings you get. For example, year:

```
var groupedByDateData = _.groupBy(data_list, function(item) {
  // pretty crappy way of getting the year,
  // but luckily the dates are structured
  return item.insertDate.substring(0,4); 
});

// => [
//      {"createdat": "2011", "val": 10000},
//      {"createdat": "2012", "val": 40000},
//      {"createdat": "2013", "val": 110000}
//    ]
```

Month:

```
var groupedByDateData = _.groupBy(data_list, function(item) {
  return item.insertDate.substring(0,7); 
});

// => [
//      {"createdat": "2011-12", "val": 10000},
//      {"createdat": "2013-03", "val": 40000},
//      {"createdat": "2012-12", "val": 30000},
//      {"createdat": "2013-04", "val": 70000},
//      {"createdat": "2012-11", "val": 10000}
//    ]
```

Your JS Bin helped a lot: http://jsbin.com/ucohoq/7/edit

Comment: I did that before you posted check it here http://jsbin.com/etepan/3/edit but "item.insertDate.substring(0,4);" seems not good, I did the same thing like obj.insertDate.split('-')[0] which is odd too.

Comment: For date parsing, I usually use moment.js because it has a sensible API and formats dates nicely. 

You could it in your `aggregateByDate` function's return value (instead of spitting out `createdat` as is.