# Javascript groupby week/month/year

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a json array with data in it. i'd like to group the data in it by week, month & year.

I tried following the discussion [Javascript groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700678/javascript-object-group-by-day-month-year)

How can I get the sum of values grouped by month & year as in the expected output show below please?

Following the example quoted, I get the output as below

Monthly Grouping's output

[image: Monthly Grouping]

Yearly Grouping's output

[image: Yearly Grouping]

Here's the data & code

```
function displayCalc() {
    var data= [{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-06-27",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 3,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 42.24,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 14.08,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 42.24
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-06-28",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 3,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 27.54,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.18,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 27.54
        },{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-07-02",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 39,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 354.39,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 26.19,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.08,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 29.96,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 32.79,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 35,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 36.47
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-07-03",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 66,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 593,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 26.26,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 8.98,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 29.21,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 31.24,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 33.21,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 34.56
        },{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-08-01",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 6,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 57.21,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 28.6,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.53,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 35.33,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 36.17,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 36.68,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 37.02
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-08-02",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 12,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 94.47,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 23.22,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.87,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 25.1,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 25.36,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 25.51,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 25.62
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-09-01",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 12,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 88.55,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 6.84,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.37,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 9.18,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 9.82,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 10.21,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 10.48
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-09-03",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 15,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 116.13,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 6.95,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.74,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 9.52,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 10.99,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 12.39,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 13.33
        }];


    var grouped = _.groupBy(data, function (item) {
        return item.EVENT_DATE;
    });

    var groupedByYear = _.groupBy(data, function (item) {
        return item.EVENT_DATE.substring(0, 4);
    });

    var groupedByMonth = _.groupBy(data, function (item) {
        return item.EVENT_DATE.substring(0, 7);
    });

    console.log(grouped);
    console.log(groupedByYear);
    console.log(groupedByMonth);
}
```

Could I request help to achieve this please?

The output is to be generated as below

**WEEKLY AGGREGATED DATA**

```
     var jsonData = [{
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-01-04",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 30,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 100.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 142.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 143.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 305.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":271.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 289.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 238.24
  }, {
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-01-11",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 300,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 131.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 124.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 347.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 245.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":345.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 168.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 458.24
  }, {
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-01-18",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 49,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 456.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 23.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 37.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 678.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":345.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 123.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 123.24
  }]
```

**MONTHLY AGGREGATED DATA**

```
   var jsonData = [{
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-01",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 30,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 100.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 142.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 143.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 305.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":271.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 289.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 238.24
  }, {
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-02",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 300,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 131.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 124.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 347.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 245.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":345.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 168.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 458.24
  }, {
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015-04",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 49,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 456.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 23.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 37.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 678.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":345.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 123.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 123.24
  }]
```

**YEARLY AGGREGATED DATA**

```
       var jsonData = [{
    "EVENT_DATE": "2014",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 3000,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 1000.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 1420.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 1430.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 3050.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":2710.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 2890.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 2380.24
  }, {
    "EVENT_DATE": "2015",
    "NUMBER_EVENTS": 4000,
    "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 131.27,
    "FIRST_PAUSE": 1240.24,
    "SECOND_PAUSE": 3470.08,
    "THIRD_PAUSE": 2450.24,
    "FOURTH_PAUSE":3450.24,
    "FIFTH_PAUSE": 1680.24,
    "SIXTH_PAUSE": 4580.24
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing defined like `data` in your code.
What you should be doing is something like.

```
var jsonData = [{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-06-27",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 3,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 42.24,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 14.08,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 42.24,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 42.24
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-06-28",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 3,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 27.54,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.18,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 27.54,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 27.54
        },{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-07-02",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 39,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 354.39,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 26.19,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.08,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 29.96,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 32.79,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 35,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 36.47
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-07-03",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 66,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 593,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 26.26,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 8.98,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 29.21,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 31.24,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 33.21,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 34.56
        },{
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-08-01",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 6,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 57.21,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 28.6,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 9.53,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 35.33,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 36.17,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 36.68,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 37.02
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-08-02",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 12,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 94.47,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 23.22,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.87,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 25.1,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 25.36,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 25.51,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 25.62
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-09-01",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 12,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 88.55,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 6.84,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.37,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 9.18,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 9.82,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 10.21,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 10.48
        }, {
            "EVENT_DATE": "2015-09-03",
            "NUMBER_EVENTS": 15,
            "FULL_EVENT_DURATION": 116.13,
            "FIRST_PAUSE": 6.95,
            "SECOND_PAUSE": 7.74,
            "THIRD_PAUSE": 9.52,
            "FOURTH_PAUSE": 10.99,
            "FIFTH_PAUSE": 12.39,
            "SIXTH_PAUSE": 13.33
        }];

var grouped = _.groupBy(jsonData, function (item) {
    return item.EVENT_DATE;
});

var groupedByYear = _.groupBy(jsonData, function (item) {
    return item.EVENT_DATE.substring(0, 4);
});

var groupedByMonth = _.groupBy(jsonData, function (item) {
    return item.EVENT_DATE.substring(0, 7);
});

console.log(grouped);
console.log(groupedByYear);
console.log(groupedByMonth);
//to get your desired result you can write this in a function
var groupedArray=[];
for ( key in groupedByMonth){
var obj = {};
obj.EVENT_DATE=key;
obj.FIFTH_PAUSE=0;
obj.FIRST_PAUSE=0;
obj.FOURTH_PAUSE=0;
obj.FULL_EVENT_DURATION=0;
obj.NUMBER_EVENTS=0;
obj.SECOND_PAUSE=0;
obj.SIXTH_PAUSE=0;
obj.THIRD_PAUSE=0;
  for(var i=0;i<groupedByMonth[key].length;i++){
    obj.FIFTH_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].FIFTH_PAUSE;
    obj.FIRST_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].FIRST_PAUSE;
    obj.FOURTH_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].FOURTH_PAUSE;
    obj.FULL_EVENT_DURATION+=groupedByMonth[key][i].FULL_EVENT_DURATION;
    obj.NUMBER_EVENTS+=groupedByMonth[key][i].NUMBER_EVENTS;
    obj.SECOND_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].SECOND_PAUSE;
    obj.SIXTH_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].SIXTH_PAUSE;
    obj.THIRD_PAUSE+=groupedByMonth[key][i].THIRD_PAUSE;
  }
      obj.FIFTH_PAUSE=(obj.FIFTH_PAUSE/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.FIRST_PAUSE=(obj.FIRST_PAUSE/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.FOURTH_PAUSE=(obj.FOURTH_PAUSE).toFixed(2);
    obj.FULL_EVENT_DURATION=(obj.FULL_EVENT_DURATION/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.NUMBER_EVENTS=(obj.NUMBER_EVENTS/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.SECOND_PAUSE=(obj.SECOND_PAUSE/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.SIXTH_PAUSE=(obj.SIXTH_PAUSE/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);
    obj.THIRD_PAUSE=(obj.THIRD_PAUSE/groupedByMonth[key].length).toFixed(2);

    groupedArray.push(obj);
}

console.log(groupedArray)
```

Comment: Hello Prashant - Good spot. I was fiddling with the code & have changed that by accident. Gets tough on a long day :-) I've updated the question further. I'm still not close to getting what I'm after

Comment: I guess now it would be an easy task for you. You now have buckets of type of group you want. You now just have to iterate over all the values in a particular bucket and perform average

Comment: @usert4jju7 see the edit I have made. You can put that in a function and make it reusable

Comment: Thank you Prashant. I'll review this today/tom & let you know. Thank you heaps again.