# Efficiently grouping data based on date and day-of-week

Tags: javascript

Given a list of items sorted in descending order by date (most recent date at index 0). Pls note that we may not have data for all dates.

```
[
  {price: 10, dt: "2017-02-13"},
  {price: 25, dt: "2017-02-05"},
  {price: 15, dt: "2017-01-15"},
   ...
   ..
]
```

I am attempting  to group this data into weeks which I was able to do  successfully using a "while" loop.

See [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/85OgeHnafB58boOibWD2?p=preview) here

I am not currently able to use constructs like _.groupBy() cause the grouping clause is constantly moving .. (we we have to group based on weeks and a week could be Mn-Sun or  Tues-Mn etc)

is there a more elegant solution to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object group by day,month,year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700678/javascript-object-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: Are all dates in the same year?

Comment: no.. they could go back by as much as 30 years

Answer (score 0):

This code will create array of arrays representing each week:

```js
const data = [
    { price: 10, dt: "2017-02-13" },
    { price: 10, dt: "2017-02-12" },
    { price: 10, dt: "2017-02-11" },
    { price: 25, dt: "2017-02-05" },
    { price: 15, dt: "2017-01-15" }
]

const group = (data) => {
    let date = new Date(data[0].dt)
    date.setTime -= date.getDay() * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    let grup = []
    let newData = []
    for (let i in data) {
        const dif = Math.floor(((date - new Date(data[i].dt)) / 24 / 1000 / 60 / 60) / 7)
        if (newData[dif]) {
            newData[dif].push(data[i])
        } else {
            newData[dif] = [data[i]]
        }
    }
    data.push(grup)
    return newData
}

console.log(group(data))
```

*note if data of week not found value would be undefined*

Comment: since I have thousands of items in my dataset.. this wont be the fastest solution